# View composers or similar for Wordpress's Timber template library?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, timber

Is there an option or way to provide data to all instances or rendered pages when using the Timber library?

I would like to set some site wide data within the core `functions.php` file and have it be available to all templates without the need to manually add it before every `Timber::render()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d use the `timber_context` filter (or `timber\context`) to add your own data when you use `get_context`.

Here’s an example for how to add a menu/navigation (from the [Wiki page on TimberMenu](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/TimberMenu#functionsphp)):

```
add_filter( 'timber_context', function( $context ) {
    /* So here you are adding data to Timber's context object, i.e... */
    $context['foo'] = 'I am some other typical value set in your functions.php file, unrelated to the menu';

    /* Now, in similar fashion, you add a Timber menu and send it along to the context. */
    $context['menu'] = new Timber\Menu(); // This is where you can also send a WordPress menu slug or ID

    return $context;
} );
```

The minimum you have to do to get your data into your template will then be:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

Timber::render( 'template.twig', $context );
```